# how to load variables from gitlab to .env VueJS

Tags: docker, vue.js, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I want to load Gitlab variables to .env.production in a VueJS application so I can use process.env.VUE_APP_VARIABLE_NAME.

What I have done:

1. Create some variables in GitLab CI/CD settings
2. Create a .env.production file:

```
VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=*
VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=*
VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=*

VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=*
VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=*
```

3. My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
build-docker-image:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    # $CI_JOB_TOKEN is variable automatically added by Gitlab: see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference
    - echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token registry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
  script:
    # build and push docker image to gitlab registry
    - docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE || true # Allows us to use --cache-from
    - docker build 
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
      --cache-from $GITLAB_IMAGE -t $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

4. Configure .Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.18 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

# pass Docker varibales to VueJS environment varibales
ARG VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
ENV VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID $VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
ARG VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID
ENV VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID $VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID
ARG VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID
ENV VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID $VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID

ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID $VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID

# build the application
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.19 as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But I only receive empty values for all variables

[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong with my solution? Or do you have any other solution to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Make sure that if your variables in Gitlab are protected, that your branch is protected as well. Or if you don't want to protect your branch than make sure the variables are not protected either.
My own setup is a bit different, and I just have a copy of the .env file as a Gitlab variable (set as `file` type)

Comment: @ArnovanOordt I think it's not the cause. All variables are not protected. I have successfully loaded the Gitlab variables to docker, but the problem is I can not set docker variable to VueJS environment.

Comment: Here is logs: ```Step 7/35 : ARG VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
 ---> Running in cddaa65f0fec
Removing intermediate container cddaa65f0fec
 ---> b890c2d70cb2
Step 8/35 : ENV VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID $VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
 ---> Running in 5063533c101c
Removing intermediate container 5063533c101c
 ---> e556035d46b6
Step 9/35 : RUN echo VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
 ---> Running in aa6b29cfebcf
VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
Removing intermediate container aa6b29cfebcf
 ---> b5b6c1897d30
Step 10/35 : RUN echo $VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
 ---> Running in 09f024ccd0ab
[MASKED]
```

Comment: then I'm a bit blank as well I'm afraid

Comment: Maybe you can use script using `envsubst` to substitute env variables with proper values before building the dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I think you did fine but forget to pass ENVs on Dockerfile
I have a same configurations but passing them with `=` sign, like:

```
FROM node:14.18 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

# pass Docker varibales to VueJS environment varibales
ARG VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID  \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID

ENV VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID \
    VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=$VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID \
    VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=$VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID

# build the application
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.19 as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

To separate develop and production environments you could add **DEV_** and **MAIN_** before your environment name on Gitlab CI/CD envs and on your .gitlab-ci.yml file, like:

```yaml
build-docker-image-develop:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    # $CI_JOB_TOKEN is variable automatically added by Gitlab: see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference
    - echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token registry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
  script:
    # build and push docker image to gitlab registry
    - docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE || true # Allows us to use --cache-from
    - docker build 
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=$DEV_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
      --cache-from $GITLAB_IMAGE -t $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - docker-build

#### production

build-docker-image-main:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    # $CI_JOB_TOKEN is variable automatically added by Gitlab: see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference
    - echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token registry.gitlab.com --password-stdin
  script:
    # build and push docker image to gitlab registry
    - docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE || true # Allows us to use --cache-from
    - docker build 
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_USER_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
      --build-arg VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=$MAIN_VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
      --cache-from $GITLAB_IMAGE -t $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  only:
    - main
  tags:
    - docker-build
```